# How to get access the selected value in a drop down list using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to access the selected value in a drop down list and pass that value in my select statement so I can only pull a filtered data but I am getting an error and the chart is not generated as a result of this issue.   Here is the error: “Error: 'pieYScale' is null or not an object”.
 I am suspecting the way I am referencing the selected value in the drop down list is wrong.

```
public string CreateChart()
    {
        string DDList = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        string sqlStatement = "select   Status as GroupCategory, Count(Status) as TotalCount from  [MasterProject] where Closing_Date >=  '" + txtStartClosingDate.Text + "' and Closing_Date <= '" + txtEndClosingDate.Text + "' and GroupProject = '" + DDList + "' and Status is not null group by  Status Order by TotalCount Desc";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        string strXML;
        strXML = "<graph decimalPrecision='0' name='MyXScaleAnim' type='ANIMATION' duration='1' start='0' param='_xscale' showNames='1' labelDisplay='Rotate' useEllipsesWhenOverflow='1'  pieSliceDepth='30' formatNumberScale='0'>";
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            strXML += "<set name='" + reader["GroupCategory"].ToString() + "' value='" + reader["TotalCount"].ToString() + "' />";
        }
        strXML += "</graph>";
        return FusionCharts.RenderChart("../FusionCharts/Column3D.swf", "ChartID", strXML, "FactorySum", "500", "350", false, false);

    }
```

Comment: try: 
    DropDownList.Text

Comment: try putting `DDList.ToSrting(); or DDList.Text` in your query I would also recommend changing your query and use Parameterized Query

Comment: BTW- this is subject to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: you probably have 2 or more errors going on here btw is pieYScale a string or and Integer..? please show how pieYScale is defined

Answer (score 0):

Leaving aside that the code above is totally open to SQL injection attacks, etc, the actual error itself is coming from the FusionCharts component and appears to be a bug, requiring an update to fix it. See [here](http://forum.fusioncharts.com/topic/12168-empty-chart-for-piechart/)

Comment: thanks guys, but i tried adding DDList.ToSrting(); or DDList.Text in my query but it seems that it does not like that syntax.  If i remove the drop down list and only keep the 2 date picker fields then everything works fine.  I am pretty sure it is the way i am accessing the drop down box please if anyone can help. thanks

Comment: about the sql injection issue, this is internal website and our network is totally secure.  I would only be concerned if this would be external facing website.  thanks for the tip

Comment: about the sql injection issue, have you ever heard the term "disgruntled worker"? One angry person can bring down your entire DB.

Comment: the error is misleading and pls do not focus on pie scale error.  I am 100% sure is how i am access the drop downbox and passing it into my query.  If you guys can help me only how to proper access the selected value of drop down and pass that into my query then i will be ok  thanks

Comment: re: the sql injection - I've seen stats that say up to 90% of malicious events that occur in private networks come from the inside.

Comment: i have fixed it by using this:  string DDList = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value;

Comment: ah ok. then I can only presume that your dropdown was bound to something other than an actual string i.e an object of some kind? Not to keep going on about the SQL, but I totally agree with all other commentators, also by not using parameterised queries you are not letting the database efficiently cache the query plan. So it's not just about sql injection...besides, what if this "internal only" app becomes so popular your boss decides to start selling it to customers.... :) Anyway glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

i have fixed it by using this:

```
 string DDList = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value;
```